# Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS freezes with USB WiFi dongle

Tags: wireless, usb, 18.04

**OS**: Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS Linux version 4.15.0-24-generic

**USB WiFi**: odroid WiFi Module 3 with Realtek RTL8188CUS-GR

**syslog** has only `^@`

```
Jul  4 12:31:50 udbv-HP-ProBook sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/udbv is already mounted
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^$
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd-modules-load[396]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd-modules-load[396]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd-cryptsetup[424]: crypt_init() failed: Block device required
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook swapon[415]: swapon: /swapfile: read swap header failed
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for vlc...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-26-1604...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-calculator...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for pycharm-community...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-26-1604...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for skype, revision 41...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-calculator...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-calculator...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for skype, revision 38...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for pycharm-community...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for vlc...
Jul  4 12:33:30 udbv-HP-ProBook kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x84, date = 2018-01-21
```

I tried following [this guidance](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7)
but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `dmesg`?

Comment: @Jos 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x0ACrXPnkI-_BsSKjLobVdipeQ2Nu2iL
P.S. Photo because "frezze"

Comment: Apparently there was a hex dump just before this (the last two lines can still be seen), which might indicate a kernel panic. Can you show us the previous lines?

Comment: @Jos 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ORVZyy5pTkdFP36drPZqIlxd0ppUujy3

Comment: The module `rtlwifi` crashes. This may be caused by a hardware malfunction, or by a bug, or by insufficient resources. Do you have another Wifi card installed? If so, it may be a good idea to turn it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one of the rare devices that loads two apparently conflicting drivers as you see in your `dmesg`: rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu. Let's blacklist what we suspect is the least useful and reboot. Boot up with the USB wireless detached. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Shut down the computer. Insert the USB wireless and start up.

Any improvement?

Comment: THANK YOU for that information.   I've been having problems with an ASUS USB-N13 wifi adapter (Realteck 8192cu chip) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  It sort of worked, but the link speed was somehow only 1 Mb/s instead of 300!   Blacklisting rtl8192cu resulted in "No wifi adapter found.", but blacklisting rtl8xxxu solved the problem.