# Cannot reboot or shutdown after kernel update

Tags: 16.04

After updating kernel to HWE 4.15  I am not able to reboot or shutdown. When I try to reboot a black screen appears and everything freezes.

output of lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display':

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3988
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: We will need more info than that. Did you upgrade to 16.04? What version did you upgrade from? Can you power-off by holding the power button? If so what happens on power-up? Can you power-off, power-on, and boot into Advanced option for Ubuntu? If you can get there we can try to diagnose from command-line.

Comment: @SudoSURoot See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052311/network-unclaimed-on-ubuntu OP upgraded the kernel to get Wi-Fi working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Is this OP even able to get to a terminal? That's the info I was trying to get. It reads like he is on a black screen and can't even shutdown. Wait for a reply,  for more info, I guess.

Comment: @SudoSURoot I am able to power on and work properly on ubuntu , only problem is shuting down and reboot I guess.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I edited the question a bit, to be more clear on that. @Pilot6 is on 16.04 and knows about the kernel issues, if you update kernel to 4.15, which is not yet stable for 16.04 as far as I know.  Just to be clear on that too, because it was edited, you are on 4.15 kernel, correct? What is output of `uname -a`

Comment: @SudoSURoot Bet you a dollar it is `4.15.0-24`...

Comment: Agreed, probably should revert back to previous kernel version until 4.15.0-24 issues are resolved or next kernel version is released.

Comment: Run shutdown. Wait about 30 seconds. Hold power key down for 10 seconds to power off. Press power key to start up. Login. Open `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/syslog.1` and locate time of failed shutdown. Copy the lines into your question.

Comment: @SudoSURoot based on comments OP posted under my answer I owe you a dollar :)

Comment: The problem with this post though, if you check edit history and look at the first edit, is that the OP never said it was a kernel update (updating my Ubuntu), so we all assumed it was kernel update after someone edited it to say so, especially because of the many 4.15.0-24 issues. So, we really need to know more about what OP meant by, updating my Ubuntu, to know what was done and what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a hunch I'm adding your question to last 24 hours of problems:

- [Cannot reboot or shutdown after kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052438/cannot-reboot-or-shutdown-after-kernel-update)
- [After "security update" to 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu screen shows log content not login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051555/after-security-update-to-4-15-0-24-generic-26-ubuntu-screen-shows-log-content)
- [Why a system crash after latest kernel upgrade to 4.15.0-24?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052174/why-a-system-crash-after-latest-kernel-upgrade-to-4-15-0-24)
- [Ubuntu desktop 18.04lts freeze whith usb wifi-dongle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052081/ubuntu-desktop-18-04lts-freeze-whith-usb-wifi-dongle)
- [Why did Bionic kernel update to 4.15.0-24 get removed from the repos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052159/why-did-bionic-kernel-update-to-4-15-0-24-get-removed-from-the-repos)
- [Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051822/wake-on-lan-quit-working-with-latest-kernel-bionic)
- [Long boot delay on Ubuntu loading/splash screen following regular dist-upgrade on clean SSD install (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o)

If you're suffering the same as the rest the same answer applies:

- Reboot
- At grub menu select **Advanced Options**
- Pick an earlier kernel to boot with
- Monitor this site for bug reports and fixes
- Wait for `4.15.0-25` to be released and carefully test it

<sub>In your case **reboot** and **shutdown** are broken so close all applications and do 10 second power button press.</sub>

Comment: I did boot from an earlier kernel but the wifi isn't working in that.