# After recent updates of 18.04 network disapears after sleepmode

Tags: networking, 18.04, connection

After recent updates of 18.04 with a cold start, or restart, the network appears as expected and a network connection is made.

However, when having a network connection and putting Ubuntu into sleepmode, after resuming (even if it is a few seconds) the network icon is not there anymore and it is impossible to regain network access.

Only a restart will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hunch I'm adding your question to last 24 hours of problems:

- [After recent updates of 18.04 network disapears after sleepmode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052509/after-recent-updates-of-18-04-network-disapears-after-sleepmode)
- [Cannot reboot or shutdown after kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052438/cannot-reboot-or-shutdown-after-kernel-update)
- [After "security update" to 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu screen shows log content not login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051555/after-security-update-to-4-15-0-24-generic-26-ubuntu-screen-shows-log-content)
- [Why a system crash after latest kernel upgrade to 4.15.0-24?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052174/why-a-system-crash-after-latest-kernel-upgrade-to-4-15-0-24)
- [Ubuntu desktop 18.04lts freeze whith usb wifi-dongle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052081/ubuntu-desktop-18-04lts-freeze-whith-usb-wifi-dongle)
- [Why did Bionic kernel update to 4.15.0-24 get removed from the repos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052159/why-did-bionic-kernel-update-to-4-15-0-24-get-removed-from-the-repos)
- [Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051822/wake-on-lan-quit-working-with-latest-kernel-bionic)
- [Long boot delay on Ubuntu loading/splash screen following regular dist-upgrade on clean SSD install (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o)

If you're suffering the same as the rest the same answer applies:

- Reboot
- At grub menu select **Advanced Options**
- Pick an earlier kernel to boot with
- Monitor this site for bug reports and fixes
- Wait for `4.15.0-25` to be released and carefully test it